# phpMyAdmin doesn't show added columns

Tags: phpmyadmin

Since I got phpMyAdmin 3.5.2.2 there is a strange problem. When I add a new column to a particular table it is not shown in the overview. This problem occurs only one table, all other are fine. 
Couldn't find something in the settings :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have experienced this as well. (XAMPP 1.8.1, PHP 5.4.7, PMA 3.5.2.2).

*Ugly* method to solve this problem:

> 1. Export table as text (SQL dump)
> 2. Drop table
> 3. Restore table (with the SQL dump backup)

Comment: Is there any other option without dropping table.

Comment: very ugly, but since it's the only answer... it must be right :)

Comment: you can move the table in different name(X) then Drop current table. At last step rename X to your actual table.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a slightly less ugly answer to this problem! You can go to the "Operations" tab and copy the table to another database, and then you could drop the original table and copy back, or just switch the code. I have my database connections all set with one variable, so changing the code is really easy for me personally. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Database phpmyadmin is used to store which columns are hidden, which column a table should be sorted by, etc etc. Table pma_table_uiprefs (phpmyadmin.pma_table_uiprefs) in particular has columns: username; db_name; table_name; and prefs.

I found the row in that table that matches your db_name,user_name and table_name, and deleted it. That reset the layout back to showing all columns!

The prefs column is text, and it's format could probably be deciphered if you have some spare time and energy, but deleting the row is easy and you can then adjust the layout again in phpmyadmin, and the row will be recreated in phpmyadmin.pma_table_uiprefs.

I was authenticated as root when doing this.