# Alter Tabled using PHP Query, Column Name doesn't show up in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

This is my first post, and there is a similar post here:  [phpMyAdmin doesn't show added columns - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12960302/phpmyadmin-doesnt-show-added-columns)

But since no one has answered, I will ask here and provide more details in hoping to resolve this issue.  I have a table in my database that I needed to be able to add additional columns to.  I've done this using the following query:

```
$sql = "ALTER TABLE tablename ADD columnname INT(11)";  //Run the query....
```

This worked perfect on day one, however on day two when I tried to add an additional column via this php script, it appears to work from the phpMyAdmin Structure view.  The column is in there with the correct columnname and datatype.  However when I switch to the Browse view, there is no Column Name, just blank columns filled with "null" values.  But, if you click on an individual row, it shows the correct column name, and a value (if one exists for that row).

I've tried running Analyze Table, as I read somewhere that that would update the Schema.  However, I haven't had any success with that fixing it.  I'd prefer to not have to delete the table and restart, especially if I run into this issue again.  As this is my first post, I've tried to format everything correctly, but please forgive me if I didn't.  Also, I can grab screenshots if anyone is having issues understanding my question.

Comment: maybe it's some caching? did you try from another browser to see what it shows?

Comment: I did try from a different browser and I have the same result.  Also, this is on a local xampp setup so I stopped the services, rebooted the machine and the apache/php with no luck.

Comment: Did you completely empty your browser cache?

Comment: @cja I did clear my browser cache.  Still nothing.  From a functionality standpoint, everything still works, I  just can't use phpMyAdmin to browse the values.  (which will be a pain if this happens in production)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you can, restart mysql, it should flush everything, including mysql caches phpmyadmin may be using.

Comment: This was done - See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14983232/alter-tabled-using-php-query-column-name-doesnt-show-up-in-phpmyadmin#comment21049555_14983232

Comment: didn't read that comment through, sorry. Please try to export / import the problematic table, if it won't work, let me know if it would be possible to dump us the schema-only dumpfile so we can take a look at this phpmyadmin version.

Comment: @janmyszkier I exported the problematic table and imported it over (dropping) the existing one.  However, no luck.  I brought the table home (from work) and imported it into a DB on my local machine and all the column names showed up.  Weird?

Comment: Well not really, if the machine is running some kind of caching (APC for example) you may have issues with your page content unless the cache has been cleared. Of course, considering there is no bug in your phpmyadmin version ;)

Comment: Hmmmm...  I assume the clearing the browser cache would have fixed this though?  I'm using xampp 3.1.0 and the myPHPAdmin version that comes with it 3.5.2.2.  Not sure if I feel comfortable updating it manually.  Sorry for the delayed response, not getting email updates when comments are made.

Comment: Well I tried doing some research on how to flush the APC cache, but when I started the server and went into it (still on my local machine) everything showed up correctly.  I'm guessing the cache was outdated or finally reset.  Either way, problem solved for now.  Thanks to everyone for your help.  You've made my first entry on here a very positive experience.