# phpmyadmin is not showing added new column

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

[image]I am working for the new project, when I added new column in phpmyadmin table its not displaying the name of it. Its showing blank space with the value written "NULL". I saw one post in stackoverflow with the same exactly problem.

The accepted solution is ([phpMyAdmin doesn't show added columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12960302/phpmyadmin-doesnt-show-added-columns))

```
Export table as text (SQL dump)
Drop table
Restore table (with the SQL dump backup)
```

But its also working only some times and also this solution is not a professional way. There is any other way or is it the error in phpmyadmin.

Comment: add the link to that problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12960302/phpmyadmin-doesnt-show-added-columns

Comment: @user2538155 how many columns present in that table?

Comment: its having only 15 column

Comment: @user2538155 Than I think its problem with `phpmyadmin`.

Comment: so how to solve this problem....

Comment: @user2538155 give us a screenshot of `structure` of the table with details of all columns.

Comment: @user2538155 I don't think the solution is SQL code. The solution is in steps. Do you know what it means to export the table?

Comment: I have added the image with a mark. Yes I did export and then delete the table and I import the table. is it the same thing i have to follow ??

Answer (score 0):

I only know of an ugly solution which worked for me.

Export table  *then*  Drop table  *then*  Restore table

My table was displaying correctly in MySqlWorkbench. It was also working with PhP code and DB queries were successful from PHP. So I was sure there is nothing wrong with design or DB or data.

There might be better solutions out there.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I went to the "Operations" tab and copied the table to another database, and then I could drop the original table and copy back, or just switch the code. I have my database connections all set with one variable, so changing the code is really easy for me personally. Hope it helps! (Posting this again, incase anybody else is having this problem, it really annoyed me.)