# Some columns are hidden in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have about 11 columns in a mysql table and none of them are empty. When I view these columns in the Browse section, some columns are hidden whereas I'm sure they exist.

I have updated phpMyAdmin to latest version (4.1.5) but that did not solve anything. I also exported the table, dropped it and imported it again but nothing changed.

How do I make all the columns visible?

Comment: yes.i saw them.but i would to see them in browse mode.

Comment: I did.it returned : ` MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0004 sec)`

Comment: thank you.i removed table.how to dump ?you mean export ?

Comment: I have the backup.I said in the question that I've done these methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look in the exported file to double-check that they exist there.

Another thing to try; from the table, click the SQL tab. The default text will probably say `` SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE 1 ``, try running that and see if you get any different response.

If you click the Structure tab, do you see the columns that are hidden?

Do you have access to the command-line client? If so, can you test showing the table structure there to see if it's different than displayed by phpMyAdmin?

**Edit**: Have you tried a different browser?

Marc Delisle points out that the column may be hidden within phpMyAdmin; in the Browse tab look to the left of the column headers, there's a T with two arrows -- to the right of that is a small dropdown arrow. Make sure all your columns are selected there. It's doubtful this is the cause of your problem, because you dropped the table and recreated it, but it's the next thing to check.

Can you copy the table to another database for testing, verify that the problem exists there, then truncate the table (remove all data, see the Operations tab to do this), and see if it continues (that will help determine whether it's the structure or the data causing the problem)?

Can you try to export the structure only and recreate the problem on the [demo server](http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master) (log in with the username root and a blank password)? Can you post the structure here? Make sure you obscure any sensitive information if needed.

Comment: I'm sure columns exists.I can use and show them.but they are invisible in Browse mode in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: How can you show them? Were you able to see them by the command line client using the same username/password? What about from within phpMyAdmin? Share what worked and didn't work for you because that matters for troubleshooting. Are the column names anything strange or containing any special characters? And to be clear, you're saying the column shows in Structure mode, but not Browse mode?

Comment: Yes i can see them in structure mode. but not in browse mode.
When i added some new columns some old columns became invisible.

Comment: Thanks. I've revised my answer with some more troubleshooting ideas.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a duplicate to this one:
[phpMyAdmin doesn't show added columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12960302)
so here is my duplicate answer! I don't think I have enough kudos to flag this as duplicate yet.

Database phpmyadmin is used to store which columns are hidden, which column a table should be sorted by, etc etc. Table pma_table_uiprefs (phpmyadmin.pma_table_uiprefs) in particular has columns: username; db_name; table_name; and prefs.

I found the row in that table that matches your db_name,user_name and table_name, and deleted it. That reset the layout back to showing all columns!

The prefs column is text, and it's format could probably be deciphered if you have some spare time and energy, but deleting the row is easy and you can then adjust the layout again in phpmyadmin, and the row will be recreated in phpmyadmin.pma_table_uiprefs.

I was authenticated as root when doing this.

Answer (score 1):

i just solved this with a relatively easy fix! (finally my time to give back :) )

For anyone reading in future, go to operations (top row, same as browse, structure etc). Then under **Copy table to (database.table):** just change the name of the table, press go. This will create a duplicate that should be fine.

Go to the same area of the problematic table and DROP it under `Delete data or table`. This will delete the table.

Now go to the operations of your new page and rename the table to the way it was. Like in the image linked.

Image of where to go in PHP Admin:
[image: image of where to go in PHP Admin > operations]